# Run PHP code inside JavaScript? Would this be ok to use?

Tags: php, javascript

I am not sure if a line of PHP could be run inside of a JavaScript function. For example:

```
<script language=javascript>
var int=self.setInterval("message()",1000);
function message()
  {
<?PHP mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example"); ?>
  }
</script>
```

I haven't tried to run this, but I don't think you can run PHP like this. Could anyone help. Could i run a PHP script inside a javascript function somehow without using a call to an outside PHP file through Ajax?

Comment: You are not understanding the fundamentals of HTTP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's talk about fundamentals :)

PHP is a language that, in this case, runs on your web server. It produces the web page that people see, and all of that PHP code is already completely done by the time the page makes it to the user. It runs on the server, and the server only: not the web browser.

Javascript is a language that, in this case, runs on a user's web browser. It provides basic interactivity with what data it is given by the time the page is created, and cannot interact with your database directly. Javascript runs on the web browser, and the web browser only: not the server.

Since the database is on the server, and Javascript cannot access things on the server, **Javascript must send an HTTP request in order to communicate with the server in order to access the database.** In this case, that means an AJAX request. Since PHP is your server-side language, that will mean creating a PHP script to fetch what you need from the database, and putting it in a form for the Javascript to read, likely using PHP's [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to produce the format and something like jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://docs.jquery.com/GetJSON) to fetch and decode that data.

All of the different languages we have to use on the web can make things a bit tricky. It might be worth trying to get a better understanding of how the web works before embarking on big projects… but I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: @mcbeav: if an answer answers your question on StackOverflow, be sure to click the check mark next to it so that the question is marked as answered and both you and the answerer get credit for following through :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're getting it the other way around. Your main file is PHP, and the PHP parser will interpret that and create a HTML page out of it, which may or may not contain JavaScript. This file will be sent to the client, and the client will then interpret any JavaScript.

JavaScript = client side.

PHP = server side.

Answer (score 2):

No - the query will be ran once on the server, and the JavaScript will call an empty function.

Note, you should be using just `message` there, otherwise JavaScript's `eval()` is being called internally.

Comment: That was just an example query, not my actual query, thank you though because i did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print something with php. I don't understand what you are trying to do. You can use php inside javascript for templating but I suggest you use ajax.

I would use jQuerys .ajax() function on the javascript side and `echo json_encode($result_array)` on the php side.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't think i could do it, I am just trying to figure out a way for my page to query my database at a set time interval, and if something new pops up into the database, the user is notified. If that makes any sense. I guess i could use jQuery's ajax function for this, Could anyone help me, maybe show me an example.

Comment: Okay, well with that context what you ought to be doing is using ajax, which is just networking without reloading the page. I think Matchu explains it quite well. If you're sure you understand what php, ajax, http requests and json all mean you might want to check out this tutorial. http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/    You could use something like this (avoid copy pasting) with the javascript setTimeout function to update some data every x seconds. Good luck.

Comment: This post actually answers the question. Others just trying to teach PHP.