# PHP function + Jquery + Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I cant make it work. I have a php script on a website (not so good in php, so if something is wrong, please point me). And i want to call it from a js document.

```
<?php
    function doit($option){
        if ('getit' == $option){
            $value = '318273918739182739179';
            return $value;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
?>
```

and i want to call it from a js file. How do i pass an argument to the php script via Ajax?

```
var getanswer ={
php: function(){
    $.ajax({
           url:'mywebsite.com/php/return.php',
           data: {action, 'doit'},
           type: 'post',
           success: function(output){
           alert(output);
           }
           })
}
}
```

Comment: Give us more information. What did you try in JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run PHP code inside JavaScript? Would this be ok to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938500/run-php-code-inside-javascript-would-this-be-ok-to-use). Also: [Using JQuery Ajax to call a php function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842776/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function?rq=1)

Comment: sorry, added what i tested in js.

Comment: I hate how people on stackoverflow make you feel like a complete crap for asking for help. No, i dont want to run php inside js. I am aware that it s not possible. Sorry

Comment: @ghaschel, maybe you should search around a bit before asking how to use AJAX. There are plenty of tutorials online, and we've seen this question asked more than enough already. Heck, you're already passing data to your php, so there isn't even really a question: `data: {action, 'doit'},`

Comment: I have searched for tutorials, but i still have questions, so i came in the place i thought people could help. Sorry for making this question. Stackoverflow, cordiality at its best.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript:

```
$.get('yourPHPscript.php?argument='+some_arg,function(data){
 //data contain result from php script
});
```

in yourPHPscript:

```
$option = $_GET['argument'];
if ('getit' == $option){
        $value = '318273918739182739179';
        echo $value;
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call php whenever you need it

for example I have used it for calling a function `glob` in php

here is some of the jquery code

```
$('#search_query').keyup(function() {
    var search_input = $("#search_query");
    var output = search_input.val();
    if(output.length > 0){
    $('#app_menu').hide();
    $('#note').show(1000);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_node.php",
                data:{item:output}
            }).done(function( msg ) {
                if(msg!='error')
                {
                    $("div#note").html(msg);
                }
                else
                {

                    $("#debug").append("<br />refresh function failed: ");
                    $("#debug").scrollTop("30");
                }
            });//ajax 

        }
        if  (output.length  == 0){
        $('#note').hide();
        $('#app_menu').show(250);

        }
    });

});
```

There are some extra stuf in this code that you might not need, hope this helps

Comment: what if you have more than 1 function inside the script? How and where do you specify the function you want to call?

Comment: @ghaschel do you mean js script or php